# Python 3.x timedelta using values from list/ unsupported type for timedelta component: list

Tags: python-3.x, list, timedelta

I’m absolutely a newbie in Python. I have already searched for hours to find a solution to my problem and I just don't get my problem solved. Hope you can help me out on this.

I have a list with dates and entries like 2 hours ago. Now, I like to convert the list to dates, by subtracting the text values (2 hours ago) from today().

The script works if I use an integer in the timedelta expression. As soon I'm going to use a variable I get this error.

```
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta minutes component: list
```

I have already tried `str(time_delta)`
and `list(map(int, time_delta))`

```
import datetime
import re

tday = datetime.datetime.today()

my_list = ['2 hours back', '5 mins back', '2 days back', '2018-03-10']
my_result = []

for item in my_list:
    if 'mins' in item:
        date_cor = re.findall('\d+', item)
        time_delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=date_cor)  # date_cor
        new_item = tday - time_delta
        my_result.append(new_item)
    elif 'hours' in item:
        date_cor = re.findall('\d+', item)
        time_delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=5)  # date_cor
        new_item = tday - time_delta
        my_result.append(new_item)
    elif 'days' in item:
        date_cor = re.findall('\d+', item)
        time_delta = datetime.timedelta(days=5)  # date_cor
        new_item = tday - time_delta
        my_result.append(new_item)
    else:
        my_result.append(item)

for rows in my_result:
    print(rows)
```

how can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.findall()` returns `list of string`. To get the first element of the list, we use `date_cor[0]`. Then convert to `int` before passing to `timedelta`.

```
date_cor = re.findall('\d+', item)
# get first element of list, convert to integer
min = int(date_cor[0])
time_delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=min)
```

Comment: Have tried your solution. Now i get following error: time_delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=date_cor[0])  # date_cor
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta hours component: str

Comment: This is because `re.findall()` returns list of `string`. See my answer above to convert `str` to `int` before passing to `timedelta`.